Difference between executing command from script vs CLI
I am executing following bash script:
MACHINE=`cat ~/mach`
SSH_CMD="ssh -v root@$MACHINE -t 'echo foo'"
echo $SSH_CMD
$SSH_CMD

I am getting echo foo: command not found when I execute a script containing above. However, if I a copy and paste the echo-ed SSH_CMD and manually run it from command line, I am able to print foo on the console. What's different and how can I workaround it?
I was expecting both to have same behavior since they look exactly same.

Don't put commands in variables, it causes a variety of problems. Functions are for commands, variables are for data. Once you put something in a variable, it's treated as data, not as shell syntax, so in this case those single-quotes aren't actually being treated as syntactic quotes, they're just part of the data. See "Why does shell ignore quoting characters in arguments passed to it through variables?" and BashFAQ #50: "I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!".

As for why it looks ok when you echo it, that's highly misleading. Compare the output of echo ssh -v root@$MACHINE -t 'echo foo' with echo $SSH_CMD and you'll see that with the actual command string there the single-quotes don't get printed. That's because they're parsed as shell syntax, applied, and removed. With the variable, they're printed, which means they were not parsed as shell syntax, applied, or removed. In other words, the fact that it looks right is actually a sign that something has gone wrong.

There is difference between printing the command and executing the command.
echo will just try to print but not actually execute it.
So you can try any of the following 2 approaches:-
#1 MACHINE='cat ~/mach'
   SSH_CMD=$(ssh -v root@$MACHINE -t 'echo foo') #run the command and store output in variable
   echo $SSH_CMD  #print the output --> 'foo'

#2 MACHINE='cat ~/mach'
   SSH_CMD="ssh -v root@$MACHINE -t 'echo foo'"
   eval $SSH_CMD   # eval will execute the command stored inside the variable and print the output 'foo'

